# Using https endpoints for a subset of mvc 4 views

Tags: .net, azure, https, asp.net-mvc-4, endpoint

I am building a web solution using mvc 4 hosted on Azure. Coming from the winforms/wpf world, I realize there's a lot I don't know about web configuration. I'm also to be regarded an MVC novice, so I might be overlooking something obvious here...

In my azure web role I've configured two endpoints, one for http and one for https. What I want to achieve, is to have a set of public views / controllers bound to my http endpoint, and a set of ssl protected controllers bound to my https endpoint.

for example

http://www.mysite.com/home

https://www.mysite.com/login

https://www.mysite.com/account

I guess what I am looking for is a way to bind controllers to the configured endpoints, or if that is not possible, ensure that http://www.mysite.com/login is redirected to https://www.mysite.com/login, and vice versa for the unprotected controllers.

My solution also consists of a set of mvc 4 webapi controllers, and these are all ssl protected. If it is not possible to avoid exposing these on the http endpoint, I would like to respond with a http error code if someone were to attempt to access these on the unsecure endpoint.

I'm sure I can solve this programatically, but is there a clean way to solve this through configuration?

---

As a bonus, it would be cool to set it up like this too:

https://secure.mysite.com/login

I've achieved this by [setting up **two** mvc 4 projects](http://blog.structuretoobig.com/post/2012/01/17/One-Azure-Web-Role-Multiple-Websites.aspx), defining two `<Site>`s in the service configuration file. However, I do not want to split this into two projects. Is this possible to achieve from some sort of configuration?

To give you something to work with, here's an excerpt of my ServiceConfiguration.csdef

```
 <Sites>
  <Site name="www" physicalDirectory="..\project1">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="api" physicalDirectory="..\project2">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" hostHeader="secure.mysite.com" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="Certificate1" />
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use the [RequireHttpsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute.aspx) for this (apply this to any controller or action you only want to make accessible through HTTPS, like the AccountController for example). Carlos Figueira also has an ASP.NET Web API implementation [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/09/implementing-requirehttps-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was after. I've implemented my custom AuthorizeAttribute, which inherits from the same base class, which in turn is marked with AllowMultiple=false. This leads me to believe that I need to add custom https handling in my attribute, much like described in the blog post. Am I on the right track?

Comment: No not really. You can use one RequireHttpAttribute together with one or more (custom) AuthorizeAttributes, without having to handle HTTPS yourself.